# Kubernetes Nginx port 80 not available on public ip address (only private address)

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am following the tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-php-application-with-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-18-04#conclusion

I have this in the nginx_service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    tier: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  externalIPs:
  - 51.159.171.84
```

And this in the nginx_deployment.yaml

```yaml
...
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.18.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

When showing the services, I can see the external ip:

```
kubectl get services -o wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)    AGE    SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>          443/TCP    2d2h   <none>
nginx        ClusterIP   10.111.105.46   51.159.171.84   80/TCP     2d     app=nginx,tier=backend
php          ClusterIP   10.108.10.193   <none>          9000/TCP   2d1h   app=php,tier=backend
```

However, from the browser: http://51.159.171.84 shows connection refused. Same with curl:

```
curl http://51.159.171.84
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 51.159.171.84 port 80: Connection refused
```

but by using curl and private IP, it works:

```
curl 10.111.105.46
```

How to make the nginx service accept connection on the public ip address?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the issue but i guess you have to provide `PORT` 80 is container port only you have specify a `targetPort`

Comment: By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.

Comment: Did u try to change `ClusterIP` to `NodePort`

Comment: yes, it get worst, because the public ip will no more shows in kubectl get services -o wide

Comment: Can anything be accessed on that IP ? Could you verify it e.g. by running `netcat -l 4444`  on that node and trying to access it from your machine with `netcat 51.159.171.84 4444` ? And the same operation specifically for port `80` ?

Comment: Are you running it on a VM in some cloud ? Or maybe your home computer ?

Comment: @mario sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 tutum/hello-world I can access the web page from the public IP.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ? What about nginx logs ? Did you check them ?

Comment: @mario this was tested on #scaleway and I suspect it is due to a bug with #scaleway. I am checking with them and will post an answer here. I need also to try the same setup on digitalocean

Answer (score 0):

Is Port 80 open on the host ? if not enable it
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp.

Comment: Yes open. There is no `ufw`. Moreover, with `sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 tutum/hello-world` I can access the web page.